# "net use /delete" question

Tags: windows-xp, networking, command-line, network-shares

I want to delete a network connection. When I type *net use* I get this:

```
 Microsoft Windows XP [version 5.1.2600]
 (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

 C:\Documents and Settings\toto>net use

 État         Local     Distant                   Réseau

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OK           M:        \\192.168.5.138\share  Réseau Microsoft Windows
 OK           R:        \\192.168.2.18\tools   Réseau Microsoft Windows
 OK                     \\192.168.2.43\data   Réseau Microsoft Windows
 La commande s'est terminée correctement.
```

The syntax for deleting a network map is `net use /delete X:` if I want to delete one specific connection, or `net use /delete **` if I want to delete all connections.

How can I delete the `\\192.168.2.43\data` connection which, as you can see, is not linked to any logical letter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
net use \\192.168.2.43\data /delete
```

Comment: perfect! I tried *net use /delete \192.168.2.43 and it didn't work.....

Comment: Ahh, got ya. Yeah, you need to make sure that the actual resource is specified. You can, obviously, put the /delete pretty much anywhere after net use.

Comment: You can also add /Y to prevent confirmation from blocking.

Comment: @MDMarra, Why doesn't this work when you have it mapped? E.g. if you have it mapped to `Z:`, trying to `net use \\192.168.2.43\data /delete` doesn't work.